# Cookie-cut out data from a NetCDF4 file using a shapefile in R

Tags: raster, r, netcdf, extract-by-mask

I have a netcdf4 file with precipitation data (365 days) that I want to cookie cut using a country shapefile.
I have tried reading the NetCDF4 file as a raster brick and then applying my shapefile as the 'cutter' but it's not working.

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
data <- brick("mync.nc")
shp <- readOGR("uk.shp")
output<-mask(data, shp) # mask netcdf data using shp
```

But this doesn't return anything.

Comment: Do the shape and the raster overlap as expected? Have you plotted them? There's nothing obviously wrong here so is likely to be related to your data, which we don't have, and we don't have any information about your data either. If you can supply a link to your data or edit the question and show the basic info (bounds, values, etc etc) about the `data` and `shp` objects we may have a chance.

Comment: Thank you. They actually both had different projections. I changed the projection in the shapefile to match the raster, however it seems that that did not change the 'extent' of the shapefile. Is there a way to alter the projection/extent in one go for my shapefile?